# Confused about the binary code for the MVI instruction in the 8085 instruction code. Please see

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, instruction-set, machine-code, 8085

Consider the instruction MVI A,32H to load 32H in the register A (Intel 8085 Microprocessor).

My book says that it is a two byte instruction where the first byte is the opcode and the second is the operand. The first byte being 0011 1110 (3E in hexadecimal) and the second byte being 0011 0010 (32 in hexadecimal).

I am confused as to how exactly the opcode part is converted into machine code. I mean... what part of the "0011 1110" stand for "MVI" and what part of it tells that register A is to be loaded? How does "3E" tell the microprocessor both the information? That is it has to load data as well as the target register. Or is it that this entire opcode is predefined and you can't separate the "MVI" and "target register" in the opcode?

I hope my question makes sense lol.

Comment: Encoding the target register inside the instruction bits is very common.  MVI is 0x00xxx110 where xxx encodes one of 8 possible registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/i8085/i8085_opcodes.html

The whole thing 0x3E means MVI A.

From the table in the link above (assuming it can be trusted)

```
0x0E MVI C  00001110
0x1E MVI E  00011110
0x2E MVI L  00101110
0x3E MVI A  00111110

0x06 MVI B  00000110
0x16 MVI D  00010110
0x26 MVI H  00100110
0x36 MVI M  00110110
```

The color coding on that chart gives a strong indication of the opcode decoder if the 2 msbits are 00 then if the lower 2 bits are 10 then if bit 2 is a 1 then it is an MVI and bits 3-6 determine which register.  basically 0b00rrr110 is an MVI.

Comment: you should have just assembled mvi a,32h, mvi b,32h, etc and then compared the machine code to see which bits were changing.

Comment: Thank you Dwelch! I got it. I was in my foolishness, was desperately trying to separate the opcode into two parts sequentially!

Comment: likewise if you tried mvi a,31, mvi a,30, etc you would see the second byte changing/matching the constant completely so that part isnt the opcode but the immediate.  So the opcode if it can be broken down (sometimes they dont break down into smaller parts, depends on the instruction set) would have to be in that first byte.

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249242/11155208).
`MVI R,d8` loads the supplied 8-bit data (`d8`) into the specified register or memory loaction (`R`). There are eight possible choice for `R` namely `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `H`, `L`, `M`, and `A`. These eight possibilities can be encoded with three bits as follows.

```
name | code
-----|-----
  B  | 000
  C  | 001
  D  | 010
  E  | 011
  H  | 100
  L  | 101
  M  | 110
  A  | 111
```

`MVI R,d8` encodes the register name into the 8-bit opcode itself as `00rrr110` where `rrr` stands for the 3-bit code of the register as shown in the above table. Thus `MVI A,32H` will result into its first byte (opcode) being `00 111 110` or `0x3E` and second byte (data) being `0x32`.

Comment: https://www.eeeguide.com/instruction-format-of-8085/ provides a few more opcode formats